# jsTree showing raw json

Tags: jquery, json, jsp, jsf, jstree

i'm using jstree 3.0.0 inside a jsf 1.2 page.

I wanna print a tree like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/xild/Trj3H/

But my jsTree is printing something like that:

[image]

I already try to use jQuery.parseJSON(), eval();...

When i created a pure html page and run this outside my webserver, everything works fine.

**Configs:**

1. JSF 1.2 (.jsp pages)
2. jsTree 3.0.0
3. jQuery 2
4. Weblogic.

**My head tag:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet"ref="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/theme/dist/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/theme/dist/libs/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/theme/dist/jstree.js"></script>
```

**Only taglib from that I seted for this test is**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
```

**Update 1:  if i access my page direct without pass-through jsf servlet works. 
           But when i pass-through jsf servlet doenst work.**

Someone has a insight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I Solved my issue removing this configs from web.xml

```
<context-param>
      <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
      <param-value>ALL</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.ibm.faces.USE_HXCLIENT_FULL</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.ibm.faces.JS_RESOURCE_SERVLET_CACHE</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I think the richfaces/websphere was loading my javascript and doing the mess...